# Dumped video stream often not readable in VLC

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, dump, recording, mplayer

I have two IP Cameras, and I'm regularly collecting the dumped video stream in a file. Every 30 minutes I kill down the running processes, and restart dumping, using the "mplayer" command in background to generate a .mp4 file.

Basically I'm running something like this:

```
killall mplayer
mplayer -dumpstream rtsp://cam01:554/video.mp4 -dumpfile cam01.mp4 & bg
mplayer -dumpstream rtsp://cam02:554/video.mp4 -dumpfile cam02.mp4 & bg
```

Then I store all the resulting .mp4 files for future checks.

Now there is the problem: many files are perfectly readable (using VLC) and many files aren't (I'm just able to open "unreadable" files using the "ffplay" utility).

However, as I'm using a VLC app in a smart TV to open them, I'd like to be able to open all files in VLC. Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: Remux the unreadable files using ffmpeg to a new mp4. In future, dump to `.ts` and remux to `.mp4` In some cases, mplayer must be exiting before it has properly written the MP4 trailer.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked   :)